# Where does this inequality come from?

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

I am a bit confused where
$$
| (gf_n)(x)-(gf)(x)| \leq M |f_n (x) -f(x)|
$$
comes from. Could someone clarify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the assumption of part 2, $g$ is bounded by $M$, so the inequality just comes from factoring out $g$ and using $|ab|=|a|\,|b|$.

Comment: @FShrike, Regardless, $g$ is to be “factored out” pointwise. Presumably, $gf$ is the product of $g$ and $f$, rather than the composition of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: @FShrike, if you take a look at the example after the statement, it’s clear the author is writing about products instead of compositions.

Comment: Oh, my apologies. In most of my work recently the notation $gf$ has overwhelmingly referred to a composition

Comment: Oh I thought it is compositions as well. All clear now.